# GridView with horizontal scroll

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

I currently have a GridView scrolling vertically, and everything works fine. But now that I want to change my layout and have the gridview grow on its width instead of height as it grows bigger I am lost.

I have tried to simply change the column width each time an item is added to the gridview. But no vertical scroll appears, even though the items are added correctly. Is there a neat way to fix this, or must I make my own gridview? :(

Cheers,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But now that I want to change my
>   layout and have the gridview grow on
>   its width instead of height as it
>   grows bigger

I do not believe `GridView` supports that -- sorry!

Answer (score 4):

you can't achieve that even if you **nest your Gridview inside a ScrollView**. **use a Gallery control instead of Gridview Control** =),