# How to make a 2-dimension image gallery with both horizontal and vertical scrolling?

Tags: android, gridview, listview, image-gallery

I'm new to Android and I want to make an image gallery where each column is a category, and users can scroll both vertically and horizontally.

I found a useful post about how to display list of images [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459729/how-to-display-list-of-images-in-listview-in-android). I'm wondering if it's possible to nest lists of image inside of a gallery view?

Answer (score 7):

Place a gallery into a GridView with one column and column size set to fill the parent view (or something to that effect). Place a gallery into the GridView and set its height in LayoutParams to the height of the drawables/views you want to occupy them. All you need to do then is when one gallery is moved to move all the others in the grid view. I'll post the code below. Note: the code I did is a test of concept that works, I just tried it on my phone. As such however, it is not flashy. As I continue to work on It I may update the code to make it look nicer.

~Aedon :)

```
public class Test extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    GridView gv;
    Gallery g[] = new Gallery[3];

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gv.setAdapter(new GAdapter());
        for (int i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
            g[i] = new Gallery(this);
            g[i].setAdapter(new GGAdapter());
            g[i].setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent ev) {
                    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < g.length; j++) {
                            g[j].setSelection(((AdapterView) arg0)
                                    .getSelectedItemPosition());
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private class GAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        public GAdapter() {
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return g.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int pos) {
            return pos;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int pos) {
            return pos;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            g[pos].setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(gv.getWidth(), gv
                    .getHeight()));
            return g[pos];
        }
    }

    private class GGAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        int[] images = new int[] { R.drawable.icon, R.drawable.icon,
                R.drawable.icon };

        public GGAdapter() {
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int pos) {
            return pos;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int pos) {
            return pos;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView mIV = new ImageView(Test.this);
            mIV.setBackgroundResource(images[pos]);
            mIV.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(gv.getWidth(), gv
                    .getHeight() / 3));
            return mIV;
        }
    }
}
```

and my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="1"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This looks like a great answer, but it's completely unreadable because of the lack of formatting on the code. Make sure to indent your code blocks by 4 spaces so that Stack Overflow displays it as code. Definitely a good-looking answer once you do that!

Comment: Great answer. You save lots of time.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html).

> GridView is a ViewGroup that displays items in a two-dimensional, scrollable grid. The grid items are automatically inserted to the layout using a ListAdapter.

Comment: I tried that but it seems GridView doesn't support horizontal scroll:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997818/gridview-with-horizontal-scroll