# Bidircetional scroll for Android

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, gallery, solution

This is more of a mass answer than a question, I just don't know how to post it as such, moderators if you could inform me if there even is such a thing.

This question was asked to death, and then I needed to do something similar so I work out this. The answer to this post is how to create a 3x3 Bidirectional Scroll View in android

Comment: I think the way to do this is to ask the question in the question section, and then provide your answer as an answer.

Comment: Looks interesting. BTW, answering your own questions is encouraged; the proper form here is to post the question part as a question, and then post the answer part as an answer - as if you as the asker were a different user than you as the answerer.

Comment: I now how to do a normal answer, I am curious if I could post this as an answer to all questions similar. I'm kinda lazy to go to all the iterations of the question just to copy paste this... *~*

Comment: Don't copy and paste it across all questions. If you come across a question where you think this is the appropriate answer, post a link to it here

Comment: Again, thank you, but I understand that as well. This answer isn't the end all be all of answers. But I saw at least two questions (with out looking. I'm sure there are more) regarding this problem, so I was looking for a place higher so it could be seen by anyone who cared. It could be that I'm thinking of this site too much as a forum, but I haven't found a better way to implement this particular issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is how to create a Bidirectional Scrolling View

Place a gallery into a GridView with one column and column size set to fill the parent view (or something to that effect). Place a gallery into the GridView and set its height in LayoutParams to the height of the drawables/views you want to occupy them. All you need to do then is when one gallery is moved to move all the others in the grid view. I'll post the code below. Note: the code I did is a test of concept that works, I just tried it on my phone. As such however, it is not flashy. As I continue to work on It I may update the code to make it look nicer.

~Aedon :)

This is a general answer to questions like:
[How to make a 2-dimension image gallery with both horizontal and vertical scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754445/how-to-make-a-2-dimension-image-gallery-with-both-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolli)

[GridView with horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997818/gridview-with-horizontal-scroll)

```
public class Test extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
GridView gv;
Gallery g[] = new Gallery[3];
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gv.setAdapter(new GAdapter());
    for (int i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
        g[i] = new Gallery(this);
        g[i].setAdapter(new GGAdapter());
        g[i].setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent ev) {
                if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < g.length; j++) {
                        g[j].setSelection(((AdapterView)arg0).getSelectedItemPosition());
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    } 
}

private class GAdapter extends BaseAdapter {    
    public GAdapter() {}
    @Override public int getCount() {return g.length;}
    @Override public Object getItem(int pos) {return pos;}
    @Override public long getItemId(int pos) {return pos;}
    @Override public View getView(final int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        g[pos].setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(gv.getWidth(), gv.getHeight()));           
        return g[pos];
    }
}

private class GGAdapter extends BaseAdapter {       
    int[] images = new int[] {R.drawable.icon,
            R.drawable.icon,
            R.drawable.icon};
    public GGAdapter() {}
    @Override public int getCount() {return images.length;}
    @Override public Object getItem(int pos) {return pos;}
    @Override public long getItemId(int pos) {return pos;}
    @Override public View getView(final int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView mIV = new ImageView(Test.this);
        mIV.setBackgroundResource(images[pos]);
        mIV.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(gv.getWidth(), gv.getHeight()/3));         
        return mIV;
    }
}
```

}

and my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="1"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Caution: android.widget.Gallery is now deprecated.

Comment: Yes. At this point, use a RecyclerView and a custom layout manager.