# How to make GridView scroll Horizontally and Vertically?

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, android-gridview

I want to represent a `DataBase` output to a `GridView`, the deal is that I want this `GridView` scroll horizontally and vertically. The reason for that is that I may have a table that has a number of columns that will not fit on screen, So Horizontal scrolling is necessary.

Now for vertical scrolling: I may have a big `DataBase` (with 100 entries and more...) So I do want it to scroll vertically as well and use the `View` recycling mechanism to populate the `GridView` (for the Vertical Scrolling, no View recycling is needed for the Horizontal Scrolling).

I have already stumbled on this solution:
https://gist.github.com/codeswimmer/869685

But I have few problems with this:

**1.** It uses a deprecate `Gallary` `View`.

**2.** I think this changes the vertical scrolling to a horizontal one but doesn't allow both of them.

Is this even possible?
Any direction on this topic would be really appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bidircetional scroll for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674326/bidircetional-scroll-for-android)

Comment: did you tried with https://gist.github.com/codeswimmer/869685

Comment: @PankajKumar Yes, this is the first result for this search in google. But I had no luck in using it. Have you tried this solution?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar, this is the solution I corrently have. combined with a TableLayout. the problem with this is that when I have a lot of entries (and because there is no View recycling) then my activity takes a long a time (5-10 seconds) to show the table I want to show.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar, I will say again: currently I use a Tablelayout that is placed inside a HorizontalScrollView that is placed inside a ScrollView. I want to change this implementation to a GridView (that is scrolled vertically by default) and add to it the ability to scroll horizontally to gain the usage of View's recycling in this activity.

Comment: You should use `android:numColumns="auto_fit"` in `GridView`, so you won't need to scroll it horizontally, and i personally think its a bad idea to have a horizontall scrolling GridView.

Comment: but what if the data I need to present takes more screen space then I have?

Comment: `android:numColumns="auto_fit"` will do the trick, it only let the items to take space that is available, so you don't need to scroll horizontally

Comment: what will happens to the columns that will not have enough space?

Comment: You can define width for columns `android:columnWidth="85dp"`, you must try it first then you will get the answer yourself, e.g on a 320x420 device their will be most likely 3 items per row, but on a device 800x1280 it will show 4 items per row, as i told you before auto_fit will do the trick

Comment: You are really missing the point. I have tables where I have 8-10 column. So 3-4 columns is not helpful to me. I need it to be scrollable horizontally.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30053/discussion-between-muhammad-babar-and-emil-adz)