# Change the behaviour of a GridView to make it scroll horizontally rather than vertically

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view, android-custom-view, android-gridview

I want to make a `UI` element like a `GridView`, I want it's complete functionality but want it to be horizontally scrollable rather than vertically.

By horizontal scroll I mean it should be built that way and not put in a `HorizontalScrollView`.

My would be `Custom GridView` will have fixed number of `rows` say `4-5` and the `columns` should be `extensible` based on number of items in the `Adapter`. You can think of it as the opposite of what the native `GridView` does, yet it should maintain the functionality.

I have looked at the source code of how a `GridView` is implemented by Google, but I am able to understand very less and starting to make the `View` from scratch doesn't seem to be a good idea, since I am afraid I will not be able to do justice to memory optimization's the way Google did it.

I had observed that `GridView` extends `AbsListView`, so my question is, is it `AbsListView` which lets a `GridView` scroll vertically and add items from the adapter, or is it `GridView` which adds the vertical scrolling ability? Should I tweak `GridView` or `AbsListView`?

It would be even better to know if there's something which already does what I want to do?

This has already been implemented in native Gallery and YouTube app of Android Honeycomb 3.1 and above. So if anyone has an idea, please elaborate.

**Snapshot of Honeycomb Gallery app:**

[image]

**Snapshot of Honeycomb YouTube app:**

[image]

Comment: Try this link  http://stackoverflow.com/q/2044775/840520

Comment: @Abhilasha Thanks, but its not at all related to what I want to do.

Comment: Have You checked GalleryView?

Comment: GalleryView has just one row, I want multiple rows, something like a horizontally scrolling grid.

Comment: I guess you have to create one from scratch. I developed same widget in _J2ME_.You need to use `Canvas`. If you start from scratch let me know. I can help with some ideas. And not to forget it is definitely time consuming.

Comment: There is `setRotation` in API 11 - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation(float) . You'll have to rotate the images too..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is `setRotation` in API 11. You'll have to rotate the gridview by 90 degrees and child views by -90 degrees.

Documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation(float)

### Update:

To get a 3d effect on views following APIs would be useful

[setCameraDistance(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setCameraDistance%28float%29) - set the z axis distance(depth)

[setRotationX(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotationX%28float%29) - set the horizontal axis angle

[setRotationY(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotationY%28float%29) - set the vertical axis angle

Set the camera distance to half of the screen height. Then set the rotationX based on the view's location on screen. The rotation angles should be something like (20, 10, 0, -10, -20) from left to right. Later you can play with rotationY angles to get some height perception.

Do all setting in extended `GridView`'s overriden `layout` method.

```
@override
void layout(int t, int l, int r, int b) {
    super.layout(t, l, r, b);
    ...
    int columnStart = getFirstVisiblePosition()/no_of_columns;
    int columnEnd = getLastVisiblePosition()/no_of_columns;

    loop from 'columnStart' to 'columnEnd' 'no_of_colmns' times {
        // set the camera distance and rotationX to views
        // depending on the position of a view on screen.
    }
}
```

Comment: that rotates the GridView by 90 degrees, I want the angle to be depressed in z axis, I mean it should feel like it has been punched, more like a cylindrical view.

Comment: Giving a 3d look is not so easy.. You will have to write a custom ViewGroup.

Comment: how can I make it scroll horizontally?

Comment: Its still scrolling vertically? can you paste the result snapshot?

Comment: Can you please brief your answer a bit, I am unable to understand it,

Comment: While this should work in theory, it's not really usable in practice. It's very much possible to rotate the GridView, but the height and width remains the same. This means that some of the GridView will be cut off.