# How to split Linear Layout in to two columns?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have to split a Single Linear layout into a Two Columns(**Like newspaper Columns**).The linear layout contain **text-view** and **image-view**

I have taken the screen width and have divided it to half and made the `TextView` and `ImageView` to come in a first column , ie, `A B C`  blocks in the picture below.. now the remaining `TextView` and '`ImageView` has to go to next column like in `D E F` like that it goes on.So it would be helpful if anyone gives me any code or ideas to implement this.. I tried with `GridView` which is not suitable for my issue. *Since the `TextView` and `ImageView` sizes are not definite.*

[image]

I don't know how to split Liner layout.
I tried with calculating the rootlayout height 
like this

```
linearLayout.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int linsize=linearLayout.getHeight();
                int relsize=root.getHeight();
                int textsize=txt1.getHeight();
                mainheight=relsize;
                subheight=linsize;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Linerlayout "+linsize, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Relative layout"+relsize, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text height "+textsize, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(mainheight==subheight)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "make a new linear layout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    createsubview();
                }
            }
        });
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Adaptive Ui - You can refer - http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui.html

Comment: Why not use a `RelativeLayout` which automatically does the same?

Comment: Will you share a demo video link or app screenshot example ?

Comment: @Nezam how can achieve this by Relative Layout

Comment: @ShreeshaS: any luck with your question, what you ended up doing?

Comment: @AhmadKayyali hi i didn't get answer for this question.If you know any ideas about this please let me know

Comment: @ShreeshaS: actually I am still at the begging of my research, I am starting to think it could be a WebView with HTML loaded inside, what do you think?

Comment: yes you can load huge text in to webview but what about images comes b/w Text

Comment: @ShreeshaS Did you find any solution to this ? If so please post the answer here, I have the same requirement.

Answer (score 8):

You could easily do this with nested `LinearLayouts`:

```
 <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/item" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                content here/>

            <TextView
                content here/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Then all that you need to do is put A, B and C in the first vertical layout, and D, E and F in the second.

Comment: With all due respect, may I ask why? Android's XML layout is there for your benefit, and is part of their design guidelines. Alternatively, if there's a specific reason for not using XML, it's really easy to define exactly the same above layout in code, setting the weights and placement manually

Answer (score 1):

> > You can't do it with GridView. You would have to create a custom view to do this.

if you know how big your grid items are, you can cut some corners. GridView is complicated mostly because it deals with items of any size and loads them dynamically. An easier way for you might be:

1.Create a HorizontalScrollView with a horizontal LinearLayout inside.

2.Determining how many rows of your item will fit on the screen. Call this rows.

3.while you still have items you need to layout:

```
    1.Create a vertical LinearLayout, adding rows or less items to it.
    2.Add your new vertical LinearLayout to the horizontal one.
```

There are some downsides versus what a "horizontal GridView" would get you:

```
1.All the views are loaded up immediately, which is bad for huge lists of items.
2.You need to know how big your items are, and they need to be the same size.
```

Upsides:

```
1.It's very easy to implement.
```

[for more inf plz see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354292/possible-to-fill-a-grid-like-view-by-column-rather-than-by-row)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);//ScrollView
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this); //root LinearLayout
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);//with horizontal orientation
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f);
    LinearLayout l2 = new LinearLayout(this); //sub linearlayout
    l2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);//with vertical orientation
    l2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    LinearLayout l3 = new LinearLayout(this); //sub linearlayout
    l3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);//with vertical orientation
    l3.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    int totalvalues=41;     //i take count as 41
    for(int i=0;i<totalvalues;i++){  // add the buttons in the layout based on condition
        Button okButton=new Button(this);
        okButton.setText("Button"+i);
        if(i<=totalvalues/2){
        l2.addView(okButton);
        }
        else{
        l3.addView(okButton);   
        }
    }
    ll.addView(l2);   //add sub linearlayout to root linearlayout
    ll.addView(l3);  //add sub linearlayout to root linearlayout

    scrollView.addView(ll); //add the root linearlayout to scrollview

    setContentView(scrollView);


}
```

Comment: bro my question is how can i know how to place 6 item in left and remaining in right

Comment: yes you are saying correct but you are dividing the view by manually.So i want fill the view diagrammatically means while adding sub-view i should check is their a space to add.

Comment: you are dividing contents by numbers like totalvalues/2.But in my case i have to divide content by screen size(If view is reached to bottom of screen) then i have to create a view in right side.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float dpW = 0f;
int pixelsW = (int) (metrics.density * dpW + 0.5f);
TableLayout.LayoutParams lp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(pixelsW, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
TextView txt = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
ImageView img = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
txt.setLayoutParams(lp);
img.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Using TableLayout's LayoutParams, you can set the weight of the view, which, as you know, must be 1. We also use DisplayMetrics to convert a float into the "dp" format used in xml.

EDIT:

You can also set this LayoutParams to a LinearLayout.