# Android Multiple Textviews auto adjust one big text

Tags: android, text, textview, flipview

I am working on Book application.Let me give you all concept

There is one big text and have Multiple Textviews as per length of the Text.

I have to show one text(part of big text) which appear in the screen(No scroll).if other text not visible to the user,than other text should appear in the other textview (Next page).

as i googling , I can't find a way to take length of the text which is appear in the one textview (one page).So I can take other text in the other page

I have attached some image for clear the concepts.

[image]

[image]

Please suggest me. **What can i do for that?** Thank in advance

Comment: different font have different glyph size and each character in that too. if you calculate pixels in each character you have to combine them screen dimentions

Comment: what you are trying to do is doable but involves lots of calculation.

Comment: One other thing you can do is to set specific characters in one textview and then divided rest in multiple textviews.

Comment: Yes,There is many calculation. Have you any calculation tips? I confused . How to do that?

Comment: what you want to actually know ?

Comment: Measuring Text length (According to font of text ) which is set and fit in the mobile screen without scroll, So I can calculate and set all text to the screen with  partition of big text with that length.

Comment: you can get width of the text using `textView.getTextbounds()` method

Comment: there is a very good explaination [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7579469/1061944)

Answer (score 0):

ok there are three solutions

1. if you calculate screen sizes  and use  sizes like small medium and large.
2. and you just divide your data  and set in textview.

Get number of lines of text that will fit on the screen than Measure how much text will fit across the TextView. Calculate Total amount of text to fill the TextView is approximately.

```
    private void TextMeasure(String text,
                         TextView tvl, TextView tvr) {
    int linesPerScreen = tvl.getHeight() / (tvl.getLineHeight() + (int) tvl.getLineSpacingExtra());
    Paint paint = tvl.getPaint();
    int textWidth = paint.breakText(text, 0, text.length(),
            true, tvl.getWidth(), null);
    int totalText = textWidth * linesPerScreen;
    String leftText = text.substring(0, totalText);
    String rightText = text.substring(totalText,
            text.length());
    tvl.setText(leftText);
    tvr.setText(rightText);
}
```

[source](http://www.accella.net/multi-column-text-displays-in-android/)

probably this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269517/how-to-split-linear-layout-in-to-two-columns) help you out.

Comment: Here `tvl.getLineSpacingExtra()` and `linesPerScreen` always return 0

Comment: when you try this you find that tv.getHeight() returns 0 at this time. The reason is that the view for the activity has not been laid out yet so the TextView has no height. How to deal with this? There are several ways but the easiest is to post a Runnable to the TextViewâ€™s message queue. The Runnable will be called when after the TextView layout is complete.