# How to break a cardview in multiple columns to make all the content visible in parts?

Tags: android, android-cardview, cardslib

I am working on a POS system which needs a delivery screen in which, I have to show all orders in number of columns of list in Cardview.

Something like shown in this image:

[image]

I am using [cardslib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib) to get the cardsview in my app. Can you please help me to implement this type of layout with cardslib. Or Can you suggest me what will I have to do to have this kinda layout in my app??

I also tried [twowayview](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) but couldn't get the idea for breaking the card in multiple columns just like the yellow card shown in above image. Please help me..

Comment: is number of view per column dynamic or static?

Comment: Number of views will be dynamic as new items can add up in a order.

Comment: [UPDATE]
I did more digging about this issue and found a similar question {http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269517/how-to-split-linear-layout-in-to-two-columns}. But still no solution for dynamic/adaptive ui(if fields from a card are reduced or increased).

I found another git repo, {https://github.com/suanmiao/flowlayout} and tried to implement but still couldn't find the required solution. Please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a workaround for this query. I found a [twoway- gridview lib](https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview) which did help me to add data vertically and scroll horizontally. I used this library by keeping number of rows and columns constants according to screen size and referred them in gridView. Following code is the one which is used from the above library.

```
<com.jess.ui.TwoWayGridView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/horz_gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFC4C4C4"
    app:cacheColorHint="#E8E8E8"
    app:verticalSpacing="-4dp"
    app:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    app:stretchMode="none"
    app:scrollDirectionPortrait="horizontal"
    app:scrollDirectionLandscape="horizontal"
    app:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Then, Just make a layout to fill each cell of gridView with. You have to create an adapter to fill each cell of the grid with respective content.

I just assumed that each cell of grid will have single line of the view. No multiple lines in a single cell. To show start and end of a card, You can use different background colors to the starting and ending cells.

In short: You have to make a List of data which u have to put it in grid with the help of adapter.

You can refer this [tutorial](http://www.hoverdroids.com/2013/11/17/android-horizontal-and-vertical-gridview-tutorial/) to use above library.