# 2 Recycler Views Within a Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm having issues with the UI not being properly bound with the recycler view or at least not what I intend to happen. The following image is the two recycler views beside one another. Everything looks fine, but when I run the app, the children within the recycler views extend off-screen. The second image shows that.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to divide `Linearlayout` in two part . Set weight to both recycler View accordingly .. Add the xml part with question instead of Images . images does not help in this case .

Comment: the reason i removed the android studio tag was because it seemed like you were not asking about a feature of the IDE itself and rather just added the tag because you're using the IDE

Comment: I found someone who was more knowledgeable who was able to answer all my questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269517/how-to-split-linear-layout-in-to-two-columns
thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using one adapter, you can basically use `GridLayoutManager` for that. So, you can have 2 columns on your recycler view.

To do that with Kotlin code, just add below functionality to your recycler view reference in your fragment or activity.

```kotlin
recyclerView.apply {
   layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
}
```

Also, there is another way to do that in XML. You can use, `app:layoutManager` and `app:spanCount` in your recycler view.

```xml
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    app:spanCount="2" />
```