# Horizontal scrolling in android gridview

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

I have a grid view in my application and i need to scroll it horizontally.I have tried changing the gridview to gallery.But then only one row is available,but i need different rows as in a grid view.So basically what i need is a gridview that can be scrolled horizontally.Is there any efficient way to do this?Thanks in advance.

Regards 
Anu

Hi,Thanks for the reply.i have tried using a Gallery and implement an adapter that provides a multirow view in its getView method.

My java file is:

```
public class Gridview extends Activity 
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    g.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(this));

    g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(Gridview.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;

    private Integer[] mImageIds = {
            R.drawable.icon,
            R.drawable.icon,
            R.drawable.icon,
            R.drawable.icon,
            R.drawable.icon,
            R.drawable.icon,
            R.drawable.icon,
    };

    public GridAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
        mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mImageIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      View v;
       if(convertView==null)
       {
       LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
       v = li.inflate(R.layout.icon, null);  

       ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
       iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);    

       }
       else
       {
       v = convertView;
       }
      return v;
    }
}
}
```

main.xml is :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:id="@+id/gallery"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

icon.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

 <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/icon_image"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical">
 </ImageView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

The output i got is : http://www.4shared.com/photo/MzUcmzel/device.html

But this is not i need actually.i want the icons in different rows.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997818/gridview-with-horizontal-scroll

Comment: I am trying to modify the screen which shows the list of all installed applications(by modifying android source).They have used gridview which supports only vertical scrolling.What is the alternative so that i can swipe that screen horizontally.

Comment: Hi, as you i need multiple rows in gallery. so that i have implemented the above code but i could not get multiple rows on gallery.it shows single row. please help me.

Answer (score 6):

I think your best bet is to use a Gallery and implement an adapter that provides a multirow view in its getView method. See [Hello Gallery](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) and look at the ImageAdapter implementation within.

Instead of the ImageView that getView returns in that example, you can, for example, inflate your own custom layout, for example a LinearLayout with vertical orientation.

You might consider a TableLayout inside a HorizontalScrollView, but the disadvantage there is that everything will be in memory at once, making it difficult to scale to lots of items. The Gallery recycles Views and offers some resource advantages.

Comment: if we go for gallery in this case, then one problem may occur. Since ImageView is not an interactive element, then you can't get focus in gallery item.(assume if use keyboard for navigating withing view).

Answer (score 3):

> I have already posted this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33373409/1788704) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35034950/1788704), but these questions are
>   identical...

---

There is a nice solution in Android from now on : [HorizontalGridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/HorizontalGridView.html).

### 1. Gradle dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:23.1.0'
}
```

---

### 2. Add it in your layout

**your_activity.xml**

```
<!-- your stuff before... -->
        <android.support.v17.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            />
<!-- your stuff after... -->
```

---

### 3. Layout grid element

Create a layout for your grid element ( **grid_element.xml** ). I have created a simple one with only one button in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

### 4. Create an adapter

Highly inspired by this link : https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/4c189fb1124df4556058

```
public class GridElementAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridElementAdapter.SimpleViewHolder>{

    private Context context;
    private List<String> elements;

    public GridElementAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        this.elements = new ArrayList<String>();
        // Fill dummy list
        for(int i = 0; i < 40 ; i++){
            this.elements.add(i, "Position : " + i);
        }
    }

    public static class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final Button button;

        public SimpleViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.grid_element, parent, false);
        return new SimpleViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SimpleViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.button.setText(elements.get(position));
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Position =" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.elements.size();
    }
}
```

---

### 5. Initialize it in your activity :

```
private HorizontalGridView horizontalGridView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
    horizontalGridView = (HorizontalGridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    GridElementAdapter adapter = new GridElementAdapter(this);

    horizontalGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

True about using a Gallery or ListView re: re-using views. But if your list is not too long, you can try a TableLayout with a ViewFlipper. [Here](http://ttlnews.blogspot.com/2011/04/horizontally-sliding-grid-of-images-in.html)'s a summary of possible options/solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This post might get help you out what you wanted to achieve

[Scroll like Shelf View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161225/how-to-create-a-shelf-like-view-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

how about using a viewPager :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

?

Answer (score -3):

Try to wrap it in [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)

Comment: If you do this, then you will lose the optimizations built into the Horizontal Scroll View.