# How can i scroll the gridview horrizonally insted of vertically

Tags: android

I am doing a task which retrieves images from server and displays in GridView in the application. This Grid view is scrolling up and down. But i want to scroll this view left to right as the menu screen scrolls. Is it possible with grid view? Or Is there any better way to do this? please help me in doing this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725745/horizontal-scrolling-grid-view

Comment: You can try for "Gallery View"..

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your gridview.

```
android:scrollbars="horizontal"
```

for ex:

```
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"                
            android:animationCache="true"                
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:scrollingCache="false" >
        </GridView>
```