# How to make grid view scroll horizontally not vertically in android?

Tags: android, grid, horizontal-scrolling

I have a dynamic Grid View. Means its content varies. So, if the number of items increases it makes vertical scroll. I want to make it as horizontal scroll.

Please suggest some solution for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725745/horizontal-scrolling-grid-view

Comment: I tried this. But it was asking for fixed content in the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try putting the `GridView` in a `HorizontalScrollView`. You may try to set fixed height to the `GridView` inside the `HorizontalScrollView`.

Then you can dynamically calculate the number of columns of the `GridView` based on your content and use `setNumColumns(int)` method to set it.

Comment: Great idea! Will definitely try it.

Comment: It doesn't work. It just tries to crunch all the items into the viewport, yet no horizontal scroll appears

Comment: You may try to set fixed width to the `GridView` inside the `HorizontalScrollView`.

Comment: This defies the whole idea of `GridView` (as an `AdapterView`) and views reusing

Answer (score 5):

```
        <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seatLegendLayout">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout_gridtableLayout"
                android:layout_width="900dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:columnWidth="100dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:numColumns="9"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
                    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
                    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                    android:stretchMode="none"
                    android:verticalSpacing="1dp">

                </GridView>


            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: I use your nested structure and added adapter like doc says, but only 3 image appears under each other and drig is not scrollable, do you know why? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Answer (score 2):

you can use third party library [two-way grid view](https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview). it works great for horizontal scrolling or you can use [RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047152/recyclerview-horizontal-two-row-grid-second-row-offset)