# Adding Horizontall scrollview to grid view in android

Tags: android, gridview, horizontalscrollview

How to add horizontal scroll view for grid view.
I have tried but its not working. is there any solution???

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="60dp"
> 
<GridView  
android:id="@+id/gridview1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:numColumns="8"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="60dp" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: "but its not working...." Post some details about that.

Comment: why do you need to add a gridview in horizontalscrollview? to make it scroll?

Comment: Here is the duplicate...


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919060/how-to-make-grid-view-scroll-horizontally-not-vertically-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Just use ViewPager to hold your gridviews to enabling horizontal scrolling