# Grid Image & swipe the screen Horizontally for next image grid

Tags: android

I want to do following things:

1. Create grid(3 * 3) of images on one screen
2. Horizontal Swipe the first screen to next one to display the other grid(i.e remaining images)

Similar to the Grid we see in our android mobile Phone's

Any answer truly Appreciated...

Comment: May this question will help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919060/how-to-make-grid-view-scroll-horizontally-not-vertically-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this by using a `ViewPager` and a `GridLayout` or a `TableLayout`. You can find many samples for using `ViewPager`.

Here is a complete sample code for you. Just copy it(with layouts) to your project and run it. Sample uses a `TableLayout` but you can change it to use a `GridLayout` if you want.

Also read TODO'S, in code;)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PagerDemo extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample_main);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    }

    private static class CustomViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public CustomViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // TODO switch for position value to create different fragments

            return PagerFragment.newInstance(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    public static class PagerFragment extends Fragment {

        private int index; 

        // This is a best practice to instantiate a Fragment
        public static Fragment newInstance(int index) {
            // TODO: Change your newInstance method with new parameters for your need           
            PagerFragment f = new PagerFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("index", index);
            f.setArguments(args);
            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            index = getArguments().getInt("index", 0);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_table_layout, null);
            return root;
        }    
    }
}
```

sample.xml under res/layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

sample_table_layout.xml under res/layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```