# how can i make this one row Grid view scrolling horizontally

Tags: android, xml, gridview, scroll

this is the Gridview i want it to scroll horizontally

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_contactus"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:verticalSpacing="50dp" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725745/horizontal-scrolling-grid-view and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919060/how-to-make-grid-view-scroll-horizontally-not-vertically-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use gallery instead of gridview. or use horizontalscrollview if you are using newer android versions