# How to offset second column of a RecyclerView in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I currently am developping an Android app in which I use a recyclerView to show the user a list of available services of the app. Right now the list's UI is a simple two-columns, scrollable recyclerView who look like the items are snapped just like in a gridview.

I'd like to offset the second column of the recyclerView so it would look kinda like how a keyboard's keys rows do, not aligning items perfectly.

I've seen another question that asks for the same thing as me (though horizontally and not vertically) but the answers didn't help and I don't want to necromance the thread back to life  ^^
[RecyclerView - horizontal, two-row grid, second row offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047152/recyclerview-horizontal-two-row-grid-second-row-offset)

Does anyone know of a way to do this ? maybe a library exists somewhere but I looked everywhere I could find answers without success...

Edit : Thanks to Bled K. for the solution :D I added this function and called it in the OnBindViewHolder :

```
public void setViewOffset(int position){
            if(position==1){
                ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) this.f.getLayoutParams();
                params.topMargin = cardView.getHeight()/3;
                this.f.setLayoutParams(params);
            }else{
                ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) this.f.getLayoutParams();
                params.topMargin = 0;
                this.f.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        }
```

in my case this.f is the constraintLayout that contains my cardview and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using your own `Adapter` and `ViewHolder`. Create a method inside your custom ViewHolder say ... `void setViewOffset(int position)` where you'd set a different left margin to the view if the position is the one you want. Call this method in your adapter's `onBindViewHolder(int position)` and pass the possition.

Otherwise, a bit of code from your side would allow for more help.