# How can i change GridView scrolling type?

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-scroll

I would like to change the GridView scrolling style to scroll a section (like with ViewPager) instead of one line at a time. 
Can any one tell me what is the best way to implement this behavior without using any third party library?

Comment: Will recyclerView suit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Here there is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919060/how-to-make-grid-view-scroll-horizontally-not-vertically-in-android) that explain how to use GridView with an horizontal scroll, that as far as I understand is what you are trying to achieve if you want to make it work as a ViewPager

Basically you insert the GridView 
inside an **HorizontalScrollView**

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seatLegendLayout">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout_gridtableLayout"
                android:layout_width="900dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:columnWidth="100dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:numColumns="9"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
                    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
                    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                    android:stretchMode="none"
                    android:verticalSpacing="1dp">

                </GridView>


            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Is that will scroll a numerous of columns instead of one each time ?

Comment: do you want to scroll horizontally or vertically? this is not clear

Comment: I want a grid view paging. Im adding a video which present what i want: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=jsAWx5zWo-Q  (move to the end) I'm not doing that because i want something easier instead of using two adapters