# How can I fill array of Images both vertically and horizontally in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Goal: To make display array of images vertically and horizontally

The task is to make it infinitely go to right and left, it already works up and down but when I want to go to the right it doesn't. It need to be for whatever the size of the image and no matter the amount of the images as well as the column number.

I have tried these methods but none gave me the result I wanted:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6716638/8889248

[How to make grid view scroll horizontally not vertically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919060/how-to-make-grid-view-scroll-horizontally-not-vertically-in-android)

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


         <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
            android:columnWidth="200dp"
            android:numColumns="4"
            android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
             android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
             android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
             android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            >

         </GridView>




</LinearLayout>
```

grid_single.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
    
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/grid_image"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp" ></ImageView>


</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.gridview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView grid;

    int[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.dog,
            R.drawable.elephant,
            R.drawable.tiger,
            R.drawable.fish,
            R.drawable.wolf,
            R.drawable.lion,
            R.drawable.horse,
            R.drawable.house,
            R.drawable.monkey,
            R.drawable.restaurant,
            R.drawable.fox,
            R.drawable.shark,
            R.drawable.nerd,
            R.drawable.confused,
            R.drawable.laughing
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this,  imageId);
        grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gv);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }

}
```

CustomGrid.java

```
 package com.example.gridview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;

    private final int[] Imageid;

    public CustomGrid(Context c, int[] Imageid ) {
        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Imageid.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);


        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        return grid;
    }
}
```

[width:200dp, height:200dp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luThp.png)

[width:70dp, height:70dp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztRyX.png)

Comment: Help me understand this..!! You have a grid with four columns and you want a horizont scrolling option for that right..??

Comment: Yes, but I want it to work for n columns

Comment: So that means you want one row but n columns! Right

Comment: no, n rows and n columns

Comment: I believe that's not possible say you have 100 pictures and want to load them then their is nCr ways to make this and that won't give you a nice app experience. Have you ever seen this type of behavior earlier..??

Comment: What am I trying to do is a display some squared images for a site. let's say for example I have 100 images therefor it will be in 20 columns so there will be 5 rows and I would like to be able to display all the images by scrolling left and right as well as up and down

Comment: In android you need to specify the row or colum count to display the items inside it. I don't think android allow such feature you're trying to achieve

Comment: I will look deeper and If I found a solution will share it with you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think I Figured Out What Exactly You Want To Do.

I Researched And Found Out How To Do It Using This Link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36128774/15392527

Change Your activity_main.xml To This:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="900dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/gv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:columnWidth="200dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
                    android:numColumns="4"
                    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
                    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                    android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                </GridView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```