# Listview with column flow

Tags: android, listview, multiple-columns

I want to add views to Horizontal listview (custom). The way i want to add them is:

- Add a view (all views will be of width screenWidth/2) at top left of
  the screen.
- Add next view below that view.
- Keep adding till the bottom of the screen is reached. When there is
  no space for another view to sit, start adding to a new "column".

I have achieved this with a simple LinearLayout, now i am not getting any ideas how to do it with a ListView. The reason behind choosing a list view is that my app might contain thousands of such child views, and list view helps in keeping only those views i nmemory that are currerly needed.

Any help is appreciated guys.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to place `GridView` in `HorisontalScrollView` and sweat a bit to make it work. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725745/horizontal-scrolling-grid-view/24744374#24744374)