# GridView animated HORIZONTAL sliding

Tags: android, android-animation, android-gridview

For one reason or another, I had to create a custom calendar component with custom views for days - different views for different types of dates - normal, events, etc - loading year configuration from JSON, etc.

1. I've created it by extending the GridView with an adapter.
2. I've created JSON-configuration loading etc.
3. I've used grid touch events to make changing of current month easy.

But I need to do this "sliding" left and right animated - as it is in the android calendar application.

for example. I've read a lot on the web, but I still cannot find any tips on how to do this with GridView.

Maybe it was not the best idea to use GridView as a base class.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725745/horizontal-scrolling-grid-view .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the following variant:

- ViewPager which has 3 pages (0, 1, 2) loaded.
- On each page I have a GridView representing a month from the calendar.

On page 0 is the previous month
On page 1 is the current month
On page 2 is the next month

In ViewPager adapter I used adapters for the 3 Gridviews.

Initially I set active page to 1.

On each page change I recalculate the month data for previous, current and next month and set active page again to 1.

This way I simulate something like "infinite" view pager.
For the moment it's ok for my task - sliding pages calendar.