# add image from horizontal image view to vertical list view on button click

Tags: android, android-imageview, vertical-scrolling

I am trying to create one horizontal & one vertical gridview which has scroll functionality.

I am trying to follow blog [Horizontal scroll](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34)

**In above blog they are loading images from /drawable folder.

Source code implementation to make image grid view horizontal they are using [HorizontalListView](https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android/blob/master/devsmartlib/src/com/devsmart/android/ui/HorizontalListView.java)

Using this I am able to scroll horizontally my images gridview.

Using Listview I am able to load images vertically also.

Now as per above blog a button is added to each image in horizontal gridview as below.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#fff"
  >

  <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:background="#ddd"
  />
  <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="300dip">
   <ListView android:layout_width="200dip"   
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
      android:id="@+id/myverticalView"
      android:layout_weight="1">  
    </ListView> 
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**viewItem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   android:orientation="vertical"   
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/image"
      android:layout_width="150dip"
      android:layout_height="150dip"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/clickbutton"
      android:layout_width="20dp"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"
      android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:padding="16dip" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/title"
      android:layout_width="100dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignRight="@+id/image"
      android:layout_below="@+id/image"
      android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:textColor="#000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now in **MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        HorizontalListView listview = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

        private static String[] dataObjects = new String[]{ "Text #1",
        "Text #2",
        "Text #3","Text #4","Text #5"}; 

        private BaseAdapter mAdapter = new BaseAdapter() {

        private OnClickListener mOnButtonClicked = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("hello from " + v);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Cool", null);
                builder.show();

            }
        };

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return image.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewitem, null);
            // Initialize the views in the layout
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) retval.findViewById(R.id.image);
            int pos = position;
            // Set the views in the layout
            iv.setBackgroundResource(image[pos]);

            TextView title = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.title);
            title.setText("newImage");
            Button button = (Button) retval.findViewById(R.id.clickbutton);
            button.setOnClickListener(mOnButtonClicked);


            return retval;
        }

    };


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Now in above code onclick of button event, they are able to get which button
is clicked,

> but I want to know of which image's button is clicked, as I want to
>   add that image(clicked horizontal grid view image) in to verticale
>   list image view.

**Can anybody guide me how can I get to know which image's button is clicked?**

Comment: Did you really mean swipe or just scroll ? Did you try twowayview ?

Comment: @Shai Levy ,I have updated my question I am following blog `http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34` where they are able to scroll with swipe image grid  in horizontal manner. So I feel if we make some changes in `HorizontalListView.java` we should be able to make VerticalListView to make our image grid scroll as verically.

Comment: The blog post you are following is from 2011.. there are plenty of much better solutions out there.... You can see this issue repeating here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576952/android-grid-view-scroll-horizontally ..

Comment: This might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236123/how-to-make-grid-view-horizontally-scrollable-in-android/33373409