# How to make Horizontally scrollable Grid View?

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am trying to make a Grid View and it has a lot of images. So I want to make it Horizontally scrollable, but it is not scrolling. How to make Horizontally scrollable Grid View ? Please help me. 
Here is my code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<HorizontalScrollView 
   android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:fillViewport="true"
   android:scrollbars="horizontal" >
<GridView
   android:layout_width="500dp"
   android:layout_height="400dp"
   android:id="@+id/gridview"
   android:columnWidth="300dp"
   android:numColumns="3"
   android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
   android:scrollbars="horizontal">
</GridView>
 </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236123/how-to-make-grid-view-horizontally-scrollable-in-android?rq=1

Comment: I checked it, it is saying to add some plugin and I don't want to use any plugin.

Comment: its not plug in..its a library..if you dont want to use any third party libraries then write your own custom gridview..

Comment: Ok Thanks, I'll use this Library.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, and I am sharing here.

Just go on the following link:- 
[Link](https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview) and just add this library into your project. After that just use the xml code at the place of Grid View code.

```
 <com.jess.ui.TwoWayGridView
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/grid_viewlevel"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   app:gravity="center"
   app:columnWidth="200dp"
   app:rowHeight="200dp"
   app:numColumns="15"
   app:numRows="2"
   app:verticalSpacing="0dp"
   app:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
   app:stretchMode="columnWidth"
   app:scrollDirectionPortrait="horizontal"
   app:scrollDirectionLandscape="horizontal"/>
```

After normally Just apply the following code in your java file.

```
TwoWayGridView scrollview;
scrollview = (TwoWayGridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_viewlevel);
mAdapter = new LevelAdapter(this, R.layout.levelselect);
scrollview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```