# How to create Horizontal GridView with two row and multiple column

Tags: java, android, listview, gridview, android-recyclerview

[image]How to show dynamic data coming from server in two rows that should be scroll horizontally and both row should scroll at the same time as shown in attached image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below java code and refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236123/how-to-make-grid-view-horizontally-scrollable-in-android?rq=1)

```
TwoWayGridView scrollview;
scrollview = (TwoWayGridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_viewlevel);
mAdapter = new LevelAdapter(this, R.layout.levelselect);
scrollview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```