# How to make buttons in grid-view horizontally scrollable?

Tags: android, xml, uiscrollview, horizontalscrollview

Very new to android studio. Trying to make a calculator app in which I can scroll buttons horizontally to get buttons for scientific calculations but it is not working. Here is my xml code.
Then I have added this to activity main but my buttons get disappeared from the screen. Tried changing it a few times changing width and height but nothing seems to be working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:rowCount="5">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_clr"
        style="@style/Buttons"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:text="C"
        android:textColor="#F75D68"
        />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_bracket"
            style="@style/Buttons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="( )" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_prcnt"
            style="@style/Buttons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="%" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/divide"
            style="@style/Buttons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:text="÷" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/multiply"
            style="@style/Buttons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:text="X" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/minus"
            style="@style/Buttons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:text="-"/>
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            style="@style/Buttons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:text="+"            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/equal"
            style="@style/Buttons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:background="#2B90FA"
            android:text="="
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"
            style="@style/Buttons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/two"
            style="@style/Buttons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="#010F14" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/three"
            style="@style/Buttons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="#333333" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/four"
            style="@style/Buttons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="#333333" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/five"
            style="@style/Buttons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="5"
            android:textColor="#333333" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/six"
            style="@style/Buttons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="6"
            android:textColor="#333333" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/seven"
            style="@style/Buttons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="7"
            android:textColor="#333333" />
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/eight"
            style="@style/Buttons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="8"
            android:textColor="#333333" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nine"
            style="@style/Buttons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="9"
            android:textColor="#333333" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/d_zero"
            style="@style/Buttons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:text="00"
            android:textColor="#333333" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/zero"
            style="@style/Buttons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#333333" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pt"
            style="@style/Buttons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:text="."
            android:textColor="#333333" />        
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Two-way GridView](https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview)

[look for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236123/how-to-make-grid-view-horizontally-scrollable-in-android)