# horizontal scrollview not working

Tags: android, gridview

I have a grid view in my application and i need to scroll it horizontally.Can you tell me how to do it.
 i did like this  `android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"`
but it is not working.

Thanks

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#E6EBF3" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Food" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Beverages" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#E6EBF3" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right|center_horizontal"
        android:hint="search your favorite" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#A1A7B0" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#A1A7B0"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/popular"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right|center_horizontal"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Popular" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/popular"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right|center_horizontal"
                android:text="New" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true" >
        </GridView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#CED1CF" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: send you xml file please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the GridView in [`HorizontalScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html).

Comment: No, wrapping will kill GridView virtualization (loading elements only when they are visible). Better make your own GridView implementation with horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

GridView doesn't support horizontal scroll.

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997818/gridview-with-horizontal-scroll and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725745/horizontal-scrolling-grid-view

Answer (score 1):

I think GridView doesn't support horizontal scrolling.

We have to create the grid view functionality with horizontal scroll. See this link about Grid View with horizontal scroll. It may help you.

[Horizontal scrolling grid view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725745/horizontal-scrolling-grid-view)